# What are all the faces on Grandmaster tower in Thor: Ragnarok?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, reference, thor-ragnarok

In *Thor: Ragnarok*, the Grandmaster tower had many faces on it:

[image]

I presume they are of champions and I can clearly identify that the left one is [Beta Ray Bill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_Ray_Bill)

[image]

And he was a major part of [Planet Hulk (animated film)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planet_Hulk_(film)). But I can't identify the others. Who are they?

Comment: Interestingly, I had the exact same question.

Comment: I actually saw the video below a few months ago where they try to figure out many of the faces: https://youtu.be/3e-bsaTvFvU?t=2m10s

Comment: It's the third entry on the IMDB trivia.  http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3501632/trivia?ref_=tt_trv_trv

Comment: The photo you posted isn’t what is shown in the movie. The top hero, identified as Man-Thing, is not in the film. The movie shows the tower in 3 stages of construction, building the current champion, the Hulk. Which begs the question where this photo is from, and if it is legitimate, are we meant to assume that the Hulk faced Man-Thing off screen to become the new Champion?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

They are winners of the contest of Champions and they are characters from the Marvel Comics.

[**Man-thing**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-Thing) - Top

[image: Man thing]

[**Beta Ray Bill**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_Ray_Bill)- Left

[image: Beta ray bill]

[**Ares**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ares_(Marvel_Comics)) - Right

[image: Ares]

[**Bi-Beast**](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Bi-Beast) - Bottom Right.

[image: Bi Beast]

[**Fin Fang Foom**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fin_Fang_Foom) - Bottom

[image: Fin fang foom]

I couldn't identify the bottom left character.

> We find that the face of Hulk is also added on this tower after his win over Thor in the Contest of Champions.

Sources:

1. [Comicbook.com](http://comicbook.com/marvel/2017/07/23/thor-ragnarok-trailer-easter-egg-beta-ray-bill-man-thing/)
2. [This Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/marvelstudios/comments/6r40ar/the_character_head_statues_on_the_grandmasters/)

Answer (score 6):

The character in the bottom left is The Night-Crawler. Not Kurt Wagner, Nightcrawler, but *the* Night-Crawler, an obscure old Hulk opponent.

https://instituteofidletime.com/2018/03/10/night-crawler/

Answer (score 4):

As BB Karo's answer states, the bottom left character is The Night-Crawler, however he is better known as [Dark-Crawler](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Dark-Crawler_(Earth-616)) from Earth-616.